# how to apply different background when plain vs footer frame option in beamer?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, backgrounds, beamer-metropolis

I am using `beamer` with a `footer` from `metropolis` theme for my presentations.
I also need to add a background to fit with my lab standards. Since I am using a footer, I some empty space left for the footer.

My problem occurs when I use (sometimes) the `plain` frame option, then the empty space (for the footer) make no sense anymore. Therefore I would like to use 2 different backgrounds: one when the footer is active and one when the plain option is active.

Here is a MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}  % Help to prevent buggus with warnings
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 10pt]{beamer}
    \usetheme{metropolis}
    \metroset{ numbering=fraction,  progressbar= foot,  }
    
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,draft]{background4footer.pdf}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{title for frame with footer}
        footer frame.
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \frametitle{title for plain frame}
        plain frame where I need another background.
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I found no flag that I could use to switch backgrounds according to the footer vs plain frame option.

So could I apply different backgrounds in plain vs footer frames ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a separate background canvas for plain frames like this:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=foot]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
    
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}
}
\setbeamertemplate{plain background}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}
}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@empty{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo%
  \def\@oddhead{\begingroup%
    \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\usebeamertemplate***{background canvas}\hyper@pagetransition\hyper@pageduration}%
    \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
    \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\lower\beamer@tempdim\hbox{\box\beamer@tempbox}}%
    \wd\beamer@tempbox=0pt\ht\beamer@tempbox=0pt\dp\beamer@tempbox=0pt%
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox{\usebeamertemplate***{plain background}}%
    \beamer@tempdim=\ht\@tempboxa%
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox{\lower\beamer@tempdim\hbox{\box\@tempboxa}}%
    \wd\@tempboxa=0pt\ht\@tempboxa=0pt\dp\@tempboxa=0pt%
    \vbox{\hbox{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\raise\headheight\box\beamer@tempbox\raise\headheight\box\@tempboxa}\hfil}%
    \endgroup%
  }
  \def\@oddfoot{\normalcolor{\hfil%
    \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin\hskip2pt}%
    \ht\beamer@tempbox=0pt%
    \dp\beamer@tempbox=0pt%
    \box\beamer@tempbox}}
  \let\@evenhead\@oddhead\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{title for frame with footer}
        footer frame.
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \frametitle{title for plain frame}
        plain frame where I need another background.
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{title for frame with footer}
        footer frame.
    \end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

[image]